# Using a Hash function to set field across multiple rows in a CakePHP array

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
Hash::set($result, 'Model.{n}.field', 'replacementvalue');
```

But there doesn't seem to be a function in the hash class that does this. How can I achieve this without a foreach loop?

Edit: made it more clear I'm replacing a value not setting a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = Hash::insert($result, 'Model.{n}.field', 'newvalue')
```

seems to do exactly what you're asking

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, there's already a value for field in each row - will this function REPLACE an existing value?

Comment: Yes it will. Try it yourself

Comment: You are a guru. I ticked your answer but I can't vote up as it requires 15 reputation sorry. :(

Do you know why the CakePHP documentation for afterSave (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html) doesn't use this method, and instead uses a for each loop?